# How can I identify a recessive and dominant gene?

Tags: genome

For example, I have two allelic genes. How can I identify a recessive and dominant gene? Are there any databases with this information? Or the answer to my question is to study the concept of "haplosufficiency"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably look up the genes in [OMIM](https://www.omim.org/), which provides detailed description of the functions and phenotypes associated with genes, including inheritance mode.

For example, this is what you would get for TP53:

[image: OMIM Gene-Phenotype Relationships table for P53]